# Auto height increase on bootstrap carousel as token-input list increase

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular2-template, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel which is actually a form.
One carousel item is a multi selectbox
How can i auto increase the height on only one carousel-item as the height of the multi select box increase.

The image 1 is how i get. 
Image 2 how i want it.

Much thanks for much insights. I cannot refresh the carousel. It will unset my form inputs

[image]

```
<div class="row no-gutters" id="mob-carousel-row" [style.height.px]="mobileCarouselRowHeight">
        <div class="col-1 col-sm-1">
            <a href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left mobile-form-nav" ></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <div 
                #plMobileCarouselForm 
                id="carouselExampleIndicators"
                class="carousel slide"
                data-ride="carousel"
                data-interval="false">

                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="mob-carousel">

                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="form-group md-form mob inputbox">
                            <!-- first input box item  -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="form-group md-form mob muti-select">
                            <!-- muti select  box item  need auto height -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="form-group md-form mob inputbox">
                            <!-- first input box item  -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1 col-sm-1">
            <a href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right mobile-form-nav" ></i>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is intended as a comment but I can't comment yet.**

Since you haven't provided your CSS it's just guess work.

However, if you set the height to auto for the container that contains the input forms or select boxes, it will adjust itself as more options become available.

```css
.carousel-item active {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: @ i will check and create a fiddle

Comment: I am not able to create a plunker. I tried http://plnkr.co/edit/yeBYvKoE4h3BKNTv9kNx?p=preview

Comment: I will upload my dev application anf will give link. http://www.isavecost.in/loan/personal need to check it in mobile view on browser.

Comment: thanks for support. `big-container` css i tried locally. I did not work

Comment: `.big-container` was just an example. in your case the most likely selector is `.carousel-item active` since it contains the expanding forms. Try and see if `.carousel-item active {height: auto;}` works.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I added celar:both ; even though. the below items did not push down.

Comment: I added an position relative to the carousel inner which was absolute earlier. Your support was great. Thanks a lot.